# Objective-C, custom style of first letter in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, styles, uitextview

Is there any way to customize first letter in `UITextView`, change **color**, **font size** and **font family**? 
Look at screenshot below:

[image]

**Edit:**
Is there pure Objective-C implementation?
Sure, better if it would support **iOS4 and later**.

Thank you

Comment: u need to create snippet for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 6 you can use a simple `NSAttributedString`, assigning `attributedText`.

The `NSAttributedString` allows you to specify a dictionary of properties for a range of characters.

**Update**

> Sure, better if it would support iOS4 and later.

The quick and easy way going back that far is to use a `UIWebView`, which is capable of presenting PDF, HTML, RTF, RTFD, etc.

Comment: or, use `UIWebView` with local HTML page.

Comment: @FahriAzimov yes (+1), good approach for backwards compatibility (which the OP has updated the question, and I updated my answer)

Comment: Using UIWebView will solve my task) I wonder why for Objective-C is hard to deal with text)

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek i also found it curious why it took as long as it did to get moved over and included in iOS (remember, high level objc text views with attributed strings have been available on OS X the entire time). the web view uses another rendering engine, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look at the [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) control which styles the text using html tag. It's open sourced, if I remember correctly, it does use something like NSAttributedString behind the stage.

Comment: Sorry for replying quite late! 
Yes, it does support iOS4. I use RTLabel for my tasks at work. To be specific, http://goo.gl/6Pjw0, a dinning reservation app, RTLabel is used in keyword searching highlighting and labels requiring at least two colors.